# Delete third element in F# list

Tags: f#

I am writing a function to return a list minus the third value.
Here is my current code:

```
let listString = [ "1"; "2"; "3"; "4" ];;

let del3 (listA :'a)  =  [listA.Head; listA.Tail.Head] @ [listA.Tail.Tail.Tail];;

del3 listString
```

and I am getting the error:

> Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

What should I change to fix the error?

Comment: Try to avoid `.Head` and `.Tail`.

Answer (score 16):

I think a simpler approach based on a pattern match might be better

```
let del3 = function |a::b::c::d -> a::b::d | _ -> failwith "insufficient input"
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to let the compiler know that listA is a list. Also Tail returns a list, so for the second list you're appending you don't want to wrap the tail in a list, otherwise you're going to have a list of a list:

```
let listString = [ "1"; "2"; "3"; "4" ]

let del3 (listA :'a list)  =  [listA.Head; listA.Tail.Head] @ listA.Tail.Tail.Tail

del3 listString;;
```

A solution to handle lists of all sizes:

```
let del3 = function
    | a::b::c::tail -> a::b::tail
    | list -> list
```

Comment: Your second match case is redundant as it is a special case of the first for `tail=[]`.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing members, methods or properties of an object, F# needs to know the type of that object. It can't just infer the type from the fact that you're accessing a property named `Head` because there might be many different classes that have such a property.

To fix this problem, either give `listA` a type annotation or use `List.head` and `List.tail` instead of the properties.

Comment: the type annotation didnt help.. see Edit

Comment: @jth41 It didn't help because your type annotation (falsely) claimed that `listA` could be any type. It should say that `listA` is a list.