# Remove every 3rd element from a list F#

Tags: list, f#

I am trying to write a module in F# that will delete every 3rd element from a list and will return a new list without that elements.

for example

```
let  input = [ 1 .. 15 ] 

printfn "List with elements eliminated: %A" (Program1.remove input)
```

which sould give this output

```
List with elements eliminated: [1; 2; 4; 5; 7; 8; 10; 11; 13; 14]
```

What i tried so far

```
module Program1 =
 open System
 let remove list1=
    let collectList = List.iteri (fun i x -> if i%3 <> 0 then   x) list1
    collectList
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
 let list = [ 1; 2; 3] 
 printfn "new List is %A" (Program1.remove list )
 0
```

Now i am recieving an error and i tried all day to solve it. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What error messages did you receive?

Comment: Some hints for a recursive approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906178/delete-third-element-in-f-list/18906483#18906483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error:

```
 error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'unit list'
but given a
    'int list'
The type 'unit' does not match the type 'int'
```

the problem comes from the line `if i%3 <> 0 then   x`. It is an if-expression without an else clause, and it must have type of `unit`, and type inference results in `x` being type `unit`. For more details about F# conditionals, read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/conditional-expressions-if-then-else.

EDIT: Also, `List.iteri` doesn't do what you intend to do because `List.iteri` doesn't return a list, it return a `unit`. You need functions such as `List.map`, `List.filter`, `List.choose`, `List.foldBack` to solve your problem.

Read the accepted answer from this post to get an idea about how to approach this problem (you will need to make minor modifications): [Getting every nth Element of a Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676529/getting-every-nth-element-of-a-sequence)

There is also a simpler approach using `List.foldBack` to build to resulting list.

Comment: Maybe add a bit about the fact that `List.iteri` also returns `unit`. Also although the linked answer is correct a simpler approach can be done here (and there too) simply using `List.foldBack`

Comment: `let list = [ 1..15]`

`let r1 = List.filter (fun x -> x % 3 <> 0) list`



`printfn "new List is %A" r1`

This was my final solution. Thank you for the hints. My problem was that i was trying to remove every trird element for every type of list but in my case, i will allways have an ascending ordered list so it can be easy done with List.filter. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you trying to filter every third value or every value divideable by 3.

If its the first case than one functional approach could be like this

```
//safe take and skip fn (no exceptions)
let take x xs = if List.length xs >= x then List.take x xs else [] 
let skip x xs = if List.length xs >= x then List.skip x xs else []
let rec remove x xs =
    //effectively this drops every xnt element
    let head = take (x - 1) xs
    let tail = skip x xs
    match tail with
    | [] -> head
    | _  -> List.append head (remove x tail)

let x = ["One";"Two";"Three";"Four";"Five";"Six";"Seven";"Eight";"Nine";"Ten"]
remove 3 x
```

However this is pretty heavy weight ;-)
So a better approach might be as you have almost found

```
let x = ["One";"Two";"Three";"Four";"Five";"Six";"Seven";"Eight";"Nine";"Ten"]
let indices = [1 .. List.length x]

List.zip indices x 
|> List.filter (fun (x,_) -> x % 3 <> 0)
```

Comment: Don't forget to only get the items in the end and since F#4.0 there is `List.indexed` which returns a list of item tupled with their indexes do you can rewrite it `x |> List.indexed |> List.filter (fun (i, _) -> i % 3 <> 0) |> List.map snd`

Comment: @Sehnsucht yeah thats even better